# Add text column to result of cat & awk

Tags: bash, awk, find, cat

I have a series of .txt files with tables of numbers, and I extract form each file the number I want. Example:

```
for f in $(find . -name "E_total_conv.txt"); do cat $f | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}' ; done
```

The output:

```
-1261.21295697266896
-1261.21748935324558
-1261.21885728710254
-1261.21737642551761
-1261.21337619301949
-1261.20719583615892
```

What I want is to add a first colum which will be used as the labels for the x axis when plotting with gnuplot. I would like to know how can sort of insert a list of strings there as a column, and better - how can dictate some sort of mathematical list to be inserted? I mean like "even numbers from 1 to 10", and so on.

Example for requested output:

```
0.0    -1261.21295697266896
0.2    -1261.21748935324558
0.4    -1261.21885728710254
0.6    -1261.21737642551761
0.8    -1261.21337619301949
1.0    -1261.20719583615892
```

Comment: `for f in $(find . -name "E_total_conv.txt"); do` and `cat $f |` are both antipatterns. The right way to do whatever you're trying to do will not do either of those things.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
| awk '{print $2}'
```

and append after `done`

```
| awk '{printf("%.1f %s\n", (NR-1)/5, $2)}'
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: take `awk` out of the loop, and it can maintain the count:

```
for ... do ... done | awk 'BEGIN { x = 0; } { printf("%.1f %s\n", x, $2); x += 0.2; }'
```

Output in my test:

```
0.0 -1261.21295697266896
0.2 -1261.21748935324558
0.4 -1261.21885728710254
0.6 -1261.21737642551761
0.8 -1261.21337619301949
1.0 -1261.20719583615892
```

You can increment `x` by whatever you want. For example to make them a series of even numbers, start with 0 and increment by 2.

Comment: You need to take `awk` out of the loop.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: You don't need `BEGIN { x = 0; }` - that's just setting x to the same numeric value it gets initialized to by default.

Comment: Sure, but it does no harm, and makes it clear what is the initial value of x for those who read it.

Answer (score 0):

Untested since you didn't prove any sample input but this:

```
awk 'ENDFILE{print (ARGIND-1)/5, $2}' $(find . -name "E_total_conv.txt")
```

might be all you need (using GNU awk for ENDFILE and ARGIND) assuming your file names don't contain spaces and there aren't so many of them that they exceed the shell max args limit.